# set height of svg to parent div using bootstrap container class

Tags: html, css, svg, bootstrap-4

I want to adjust the svg height to parent div container which works fine with

```
svg {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;  
  }
```

Im using the bootstrap `.container` class as the outer container
I dont want to overwrite the bootstrap container class so I used a inner div with a svg inside

setting the inner div to

```
 min-height: 20rem;
```

adjust the bootstrap container, but the svg does not span to the height of the inner div container

how can I adjust the svg height to the inner div height ?

```css
svg {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: blueviolet;
   
   
  }
  

  .svg-container {
    min-height: 20rem;
    background-color: rgb(211, 201, 219);
    border: solid black 6px;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />

    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.3.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css"
    />


  
    <title>Boostrap-sample-project</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div class="container">

      <div class="svg-container">
        <svg></svg>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--  -->
 
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Give the svg a height. In this moment you have only a min-height. The default height of the svg element is 150px and if you don't have a declared height of the container you will get 150px

Answer (score 1):

You can use `h-100 w-100` on svg. SVG should have dimensions in percentages i.e being scalable. And set inline min-height on svg.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.3.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css" />
  <title>Boostrap-sample-project</title>
</head>
<body>

  <div class="container border border-5 border-dark bg-info">
    <svg class="h-100 w-100" style="min-height:20rem">
       <rect width="100%" height="100%" style="fill:rgb(0,0,255);stroke-width:3;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)" />
  Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.  
    </svg>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```